# 'Grails shell' not working on Grails.3.0.0.M1

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

Following instructions from official doc :
http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/shell.html

Command:

```
grails shell
```

on a Grails 3.0.0.M1 project doesn't exist.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now `shell` simply is not implemented.  The docs refer to lots of things from 2.4, that might not (or even never) be in 3.0.

You could use `console` for now.  it is (more or less) the shell using swing.

Don't forget: 3.0.0.M1 right now is just a milestone. Far from production ready or complete.